# Magic Leap Project Setup Tool Null Reference

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, magic-leap

I've followed the directions from the Magic Leap 2 getting started guide. When I install and import their Magic Leap Project Setup Tool in Unity, I get a null reference error. The tool should pop up to setup the Magic Leap's Unity configuration.

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
> MagicLeapSetupTool.Editor.Setup.SetSdkFolderSetupStep..cctor () (at Assets/magic-leap-setup-tool/Editor/SetupSteps/SetSdkFolderSetupStep.cs:34)
> Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MagicLeapSetupTool.Editor.Setup.SetSdkFolderSetupStep' threw an exception.
> MagicLeapSetupTool.Editor.MagicLeapSetupWindow..cctor () (at Assets/magic-leap-setup-tool/Editor/MagicLeapSetupWindow.cs:25)
> Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MagicLeapSetupTool.Editor.MagicLeapSetupWindow' threw an exception.

[image: Unity Console error]

I imported the tool and expect it to automatically pop up. Instead, I get a null reference error. When I try to manually open the tool, I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Which Unity version are you using? I was using 2021.3.x LTS and got the same error.

The Magic Leap 2 requires 2022.2.x.
I Upgraded my project to 2022.3.x LTS and that fixed it.

Comment: Should be posted as a comment.